# sencha touch Ext.Router

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, deep-linking

I am having trouble getting Ext.Router to register changes to the URL. I started my application with the example for model view controller on sencha touch site.

```
Ext.setup({
    tabletStartupScreen: 'tablet_startup.png',
    phoneStartupScreen: 'startup.png',
    icon: 'icon.png',

    onReady: function() {
       KOI.views.viewport = new KOI.views.Viewport();
    }
});
```

And I have a routes file, (loaded before app)

```
Ext.Router.draw(function(map) {
      map.connect("main", { controller: 'menu', action: 'index' });
});
```

This is the controller

```
KOI.controllers.menus = new Ext.Controller({
    index: function(options) {
        KOI.views.viewport.setActiveItem(KOI.views.mainMenu);
    }
});
Ext.regController('menu', KOI.controllers.menus);
```

but changing the URL to http://myapp.com/#main does nothing, although the controller does work. Any ideas what I am missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated. There isnt very much documentation for Ext.router and I cant see a good way to debug whats going on.

Comment: OK I figured it out, instead of Ext.setup ...

Ext.regApplication({
name : "myapp",
launch: function() {
       KOI.views.viewport = new KOI.views.Viewport({
        application: this
       });
     }
   });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ext.setup` is equivalent to `Ext.onReady` and does nothing else but call a callback function when the dom is loaded and accessible.

`Ext.regApplication` however creates a new `Ext.Application`, passing in your config object to it.

Part of an `Ext.Application` is the `Ext.Application.onBeforeLaunch` and `Ext.Application.launch`. `onBeforeLaunch` sets up history support if you have that enabled, and then calls `launch`.

If `launch` doesn't return false then `onBeforeLaunch` will go ahead and call `Ext.redirect` with either your last history item / token, your `defaultUrl` or if all else fails `{controller: 'application', action: 'index'}`